# Django - Pisa generated pdf doesn't have spaces

Tags: django, pisa

I'm using Django and my code to render the PDF is really typical:

```
t = loader.get_template('back/templates/content/receipt.html')
c = RequestContext(request, {
                             'pagesize': 'A4',
                             'invoice': invoice,
                             'plan': plan,
                             })

html = t.render(c)
result = StringIO.StringIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype="application/pdf")
```

And the receipt.html is nothing unusual:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Squizzal Receipt</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: {{pagesize}};
            margin: 1cm;
            word-spacing 1cm;
            @frame footer {
                -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
                bottom: 0cm;
                margin-left: 9cm;
                margin-right: 9cm;
                height: 1cm;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your Receipt</h1>
   <<SNIP>>
```

but none of the spaces in the pdf are rendered.  All the words are right next to each other.  I've tried normal spaces and "&nbsp" and the result is the same. For example the  above would appear as "YourReceipt" in the pdf.

When I try using the command line version of pisa, it generates the pdf just fine with spaces between the words.

Any thoughts?

Comment: save the HTML output by t.render(c).encode("UTF-8") in to a file and feed the file to the command line version. what does it produce?

Comment: The html file is as expected, and passing that file into the cmd line pisa produces the expected results.  At the moment I'm testing this using the django dev sever but I've also tested it with wsgi on apache.  I can't think of anything else that could be affecting this.

Comment: try saving he result of pisa.pisaDocument() into a file and opening the file in the PDF viewer. is it ok?

Comment: So I don't understand this.  If I do: pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode("UTF-8"), file("test.pdf", "wb")) it creates a good file (w/ spaces).  But when I pass it a StringIO result object and do: return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype="application/pdf") the spaces are stripped.  Is StringIO doing something with the stream?

Comment: Both pisaDocument and CreatePDF produce the same results.  I think it has to be something with StringIO.  I've also tried StringIO and cStringIO... same results.

Comment: to check that save result.getvalue() into a file and view it. I do not know what StringIO is doing.

Comment: Plot thickens.  Writing result.getvalue() to a file produces a pdf with spaces.  Passing the same result.getvalue() to Django's HttpResponse object strips the spaces.  I'm going to take a look to see if there is a better Django object to use for binary files.

Comment: try result.seek(0) before sending httpresponse and send just "result" as the first parameter: HttpResponse(result, mimetype="application/pdf")
(I am guessing here, I have no idea what is wrong)

Comment: Nope, still no effect.  My answer below shows a workaround, but I still have *no* idea why the original way isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to akonsu the problem seems to be how Django's HttpResponse is being treated (either on the server side or on the browser side).

Instead of

```
 return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype="application/pdf")
```

Use:

```
 resp = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype="application/pdf")
 resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=receipt.pdf'
 return resp
```

This at least produces a result without spaces.  Still no idea why the first way wasn't working.

Comment: what effect are you trying to achieve? should the PDF be shown inline or should the browser open a "save as" dialog when you navigate to the url? BTW, did you set the content-length header? maybe this is what caused the problem?

Comment: @Alanyst's answer is actually correct. The issue is not solved when forcing the download of the file since the issue is that google chrome's pdf viewer is failing to render the pdf correctly. Setting the content disposition and forcing the download merely side-steps the problem.

Comment: @mark i still have problems even after utilising your solution, any fixes?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and didn't want to force the PDF to be downloaded from the browser.  This turned out to be a platform specific issue: Google Chrome's native PDF viewer plugin fails to render spaces in certain documents on certain Linux distros when Microsoft TrueType fonts are not installed.  See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=7169b114e8ea33c7&hl=en for details.

I fixed this by simply running the following commands in bash (adjust for your distro; this was on Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

(Accept the EULA during the install process)

```
$ fc-cache -fv
```

After restarting Chrome (important!), the native PDF viewer correctly displayed the PDF with spaces.